# Relatively complex Query in EntitySpaces returns different results than when executed for real

Tags: c#, sql-server, entityspaces

I've got (what I consider to be) a relatively complex SQL query to select some data for a new feature for an app I maintain at work.   Here is the query.

```
 SELECT pchtq.[sourceappid], 
       pchtq.[transactioncode], 
       pchtq.[accountid], 
       pchtq.[year], 
       pchtq.[filingdatetime], 
       pchtq.[amount], 
       pchtq.[note], 
       pchtq.Status,
       pchtq.SourceRecordID,
       utaq.fullname, 
       utaq.username 
FROM   [database].[dbo].[transactions1] pchtq 
       INNER JOIN [database].[dbo].[useraccounts] utaq 
               ON pchtq.[accountid] = utaq.[accountid] 
WHERE  
         pchtq.status = 'failed' 
         AND pchtq.[recordcreatedatetime] >= '01/01/2015' 
         AND pchtq.[recordcreatedatetime] <= '05/11/2016' 
         and Not exists 
         (
                select TransactionID
                from
                    Database.dbo.Transactions2 eft
                where
                    CAST(eft.TransactionID as nvarchar(50)) = pchtq.SourceRecordID
                    and eft.status IN( 'paid', 'audit' )
         )
```

In entityspaces, I have it written like this:

```
pchtq
    .Select(
        pchtq.SourceAppID,
        pchtq.TransactionCode,
        pchtq.AccountID,
        pchtq.Year,
        pchtq.FilingDateTime,
        pchtq.Amount,
        pchtq.Note
        ).InnerJoin(utaq).On(pchtq.AccountID == utaq.AccountID)
        .Where(pchtq.RecordCreateDateTime >= request.StartDate
            && pchtq.RecordCreateDateTime <= request.EndDate
            && pchtq.Status == "FAILED")
        .NotExists(
            eftq.Select(
                eftq.EFileTransactionID
                ).Where(eftq.Status.In("Paid", "Audit") 
                        && Convert.ToString(eftq.TransactionID) == pchtq.SourceRecordID));
```

However, when I run it in the ES app (using `pchtc.Load(pchtq)`), I get about 7500 rows, whereas when I run the SQL query, I get about 1500.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the fact that the strings you have differ in case? "FAILED" vs "failed" and "Audit" vs "audit"?

It's the only difference I can see honestly.